# TFVC Get Items for a specific date time version programatically

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-rest-api

Is there a way to retrieve azure items for a specific date and time stamp included using TFVC Client? In visual studio I am able to retrieve a file from the source control for a specific date-time using **Get specific version** option.

[image: GetspecificversionVS]
However when I try to do it through .NET code using the TFVC Client libraries, it returns the files **before** that particular date and the time stamp is completely ignored.

```
var version = new TfvcVersionDescriptor
            {
                VersionType = TfvcVersionType.Date,
                Version = date.ToString(),
                
            };
var items = ttfClient.GetItemsAsync(_config.ProjectName, _config.ScopePath, recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full, versionDescriptor: version).Result;
```

Is there some other efficient way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround , you can run the rest api for two times to get the list of items before the specific dates. Then compare them to retrieve the list of items for a specific date.

Here, I take rest api as an example:

Get the list of items before the date 2019-02-28 :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/tfvc/items?versionDescriptor.versionType=date&versionDescriptor.version=2019-02-28T00:00&scopePath=$/Path&api-version=5.1
```

Get the list of items before the date 2019-02-27 :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/tfvc/items?versionDescriptor.versionType=date&versionDescriptor.version=2019-02-27T00:00&scopePath=$/Path&api-version=5.1
```

Compare the items from above responses, then you can get the list of items for a specific date 2019-02-27.

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks for the suggestion. I am doing something similar. Getting the items for (date.AddDays(1)) which is essentially all the items on or before the required date. Thanks :)